# Duplicate local variable for string object

Tags: java

Line no 1 and 2 gives compilation error as "Duplicate local variable". But code in line no 3 and 4 iterates for 10 times with a single string object without any error.

```
String string1 = new String("java");            //line 1
String string1 = new String("java");              //line 2


for(int i=0;i<10;i++)                        //line 3
            String string2 = new String("abc");    //line 4
```

How does this work?

Comment: Each iteration of the loop is its own scope.  The same variable name can't be used twice in one scope, but you can name variables in different scopes with the same name all you like.

Comment: 1st and 2nd lines are **local variables** but the string in 4th line is **block scope variable**, google about their differences, any question ?

Answer (score 4):

Declaring a variable is not an operation. It is added to a scope at compile time, not run time.

The two `string1` are in the same scope, which is why it is not allowed.

Any variable defined in a loop is local to the scope of that loop. i.e. there is only one `string2`  If this was not the case, you could use a variable inside a loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // scope starts here
    String string2 = "abc";
} // scope ends here and string2 doesn't exist after this.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have declared and initialised a variable in line 1, declaring it again in line 2 is pointless and is giving the error.

And in your loop, you are simply creating a new string, then as loop ends, it's thrown into garbage. The scope of the variable declared in the loop is limited to the loop itself. Thus it does not give error.

Answer (score 1):

String string1 = new String("java");            //line 1
string1 = new String("java");

Answer (score 0):

What is a variable?

- It is a place where you can store things.
- It has a name, so that later you can read or modify the stored value, using the variable name.

Wherever you write a statement like `String string1 = new String("java");`, you create a new variable, give it a name (`string1`), and store a value in it (`new String("java")`).

In your code snippet (slightly modified)

```
String string1 = new String("one");
String string1 = new String("two");
```

you (try to) create two distinct variables, but give them both the same name. So, if you later write e.g. `System.out.println(string1)`, which `string1` would you expect to get printed, "one" or "two"? Hard to decide, for you as well as for the machine, so it's not allowed.

If you want two storage places, use different names for them. If you want to change the value of an existing variable, do it like

```
String string1 = new String("one");
string1 = new String("two");
```

Now, the second line is just an assignment of a different value to an already existing variable.

The loop is a different situation:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    String string2 = new String("abc");
```

First of all, this doesn't compile as well. Why? You create a variable `string2`, but there's no place where you can reference it. The name is only valid inside the loop body, and the loop body just consists of this one line, so there's no "later" place where you can use the variable name. So, let's modify the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    String string2 = new String("abc");
    System.out.println(string2);
}
```

Here, we create one variable `string2`, valid up to the closing brace of the loop. A model for understanding this process (*) can be that, whenever we execute the `String string2 = new String("abc");` statement (we do that 10 times), a place named `string2` gets created, and it gets destroyed when we exit the loop body (we do that 10 times as well). So, at any given moment in time, there's at most one `string2` variable in existence. And, the `System.out.println(string2);` statement will never see a `string2` value from a previous iteration (the previous `string2` variables have been destroyed), so there's no ambiguity in the loop situation.

By the way:

- There's no need to write `string1 = new String("abc")`, a simple `string1 = "abc"` does the job as well.

(*) It's just a model, in reality Java will create a single storage place for the `string2` variable at method entry time instead of creating and destroying it for every loop iteration.